# Deploying a c# tcp system.net server to AWS EC2

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am kind of new to new to networking and am currently working on a game that depends on a dedicated server. I developed said server using a console app in visual studio and the system.Net library. The server is working fine and I am able to connect with the client but now I want to deploy it to something like aws. I tried working with ec2, but the problem is I am not sure what I have to install in the VM in order to make it work. Another problem is that it only has 1 gb of memory, which makes it really hard to install the different features I might need. Given my lack of experience, I would like to know if there is another solution to this other than using ec2 and if not, how can I know what do I have to install in it in order to make it work.

Comment: Is this a dot net framework project or a dot net core project?  This will greatly change what you need on the server.  With dot net framework, you need to install the framework on a windows VM.  What OS is your VM running? With dot net core, you can build a self executing application which should include all of the libraries you need.  Microsoft Azure is another place where you can host your server.  Also beware of firewall restrictions on the ports you are using.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I needed haha